# Calls to OuterXml throwing OutOfMemoryException despite being the same amount of data as previous calls

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to transfer a large amount of data as XML between an IIS service written in VB using v2.0 of the .NET CLR (32 bit) and a client on the same computer that uses the same. The amount of data needing to be transferred has increased over time until there was not enough memory to call OuterXml on the XMLDocument to get the string to send from the server to client.

I decided to fix this by adding a new function to the server that retrieves the XML in chunks (shown below). It works for the first few chunks and then returns the same OutOfMemoryException when I call OuterXml. Despite each call to my GetXMLChunk returning approximately the same amount of XML, eventually I get the error anyway, so having generated large amounts of XML in the past makes it impossible to generate the same amount of XML.

```
Public Function ToXMLChunk(ByVal chunkSize As Integer, ByVal chunkOffset As Integer) As String
    If chunkOffset >= objects.Count Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim dbgSize As Integer = 0

    Try
        Dim xmlString As String

        Dim xmlDocument As New Xml.XmlDocument
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(CreateXML())

        Dim xmlFragment As Xml.XmlDocumentFragment
        xmlFragment = xmlDocument.CreateDocumentFragment

        'Add <transaction /> nodes in 
        Dim current As objectClass

        For i As Integer = chunkOffset To (chunkOffset + chunkSize - 1)
            If i >= objects.Count Then
                Exit For
            End If

            current = CType(objects.Item(i), objectClass)

            xmlString = current.ToXML
            dbgSize += xmlString.Length
            xmlFragment.InnerXml = xmlString

            Dim xmlNode As Xml.XmlNode
            xmlNode = xmlDocument.ImportNode(xmlFragment, True)

            xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlNode)

            xmlNode = Nothing
        Next

        xmlFragment = Nothing

        xmlString = xmlDocument.OuterXml

        Return xmlString
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
End Function
```

I've tried adding a GC.Collect before creating the document. I've tried replacing XML document stuff with a stringbuilder. I've tried reducing the size of the chunks. It seems like no matter what I do, the server doesn't want to provide that much text data.

Comment: This call:  
`xmlDocument.LoadXml(CreateXML())`  
Does it load the complete XML document every time you call ToXMLChunk? If it does, I think you just keep adding chunks to the already loaded XML document, effectively just making it larger with duplicate data in this call:  
`xmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlNode)`  
Perhaps I'm just missing something.

Comment: No, it just creates an initial <xml> tag and a root element to which the data can be added.